# Prepaid data/voice (micro)SIM for travel to Belgium

Tags: cellphones, data-plans, belgium

I am travelling to Belgium next month and am looking for a micro SIM that I can get shipped to my home country (UK) prior to travel.

I am a data heavy user (tethering would be a bonus too), and a light SMS/Voice user.

I have found [Mobile Vikings](https://mobilevikings.com/en/) which looks like a great deal, but it seems they don't ship outside of Belgium.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Why do you need to get it before you go to Belgium?

Comment: I'm only there for 4 days, and I am likely to be arriving in the evening after the shops have closed.

Comment: can you have it shipped to your hotel or place of lodging in Belgium?

Comment: @rs79 I'm looking at that as an option.

Answer (score 4):

Belgium is one of the more expensive countries in Europe when it comes to mobile internet. The cheapest provider I have found so far is [the Aldi](http://www.medionmobile.be/nl/web/), but they don't ship, you actually need to buy it at the aldi stores.

Similar formula's are offered by [Delhaize](http://pluskaart.be/mobile/_nl/sim.aspx) and [carrefour](http://mobile.carrefour.eu/promos-free-mobile-internet-mms.cfm?lang=EN), but their online descriptions are not really clear about mobile internet. Both are also supermarket chains, but compared to the Aldi they have longer opening hours (till 20.00).

You might have better luck with wifi. [Fon](http://maps.fon.com/) has great coverage in Beligium. I can maintain a good coverage with expensive 3G and "free" wifi access through FON.

Comment: Do you know if they offer microSIMs? A lot of stores in the UK offer similar options but only sell regular sized SIMs.

Comment: You can usually cut a sim to micro size. Of course if you break your sim it's not my fault!

Comment: I doubt it, but I will ask next time I am shopping. There is one major downside to buying supermarket sims and that is you need to charge you account at the supermarket. I would propose to go on your day of arrival to any shopping center and buy a prepay card from one of the major operators (base, mobistar, or proximus). In the time between arrival and buying you sim card, you could use your wifi connection through fon, which as I have already said, have great coverage in Belgium